# Can Joomla send the user an email when admin approves them?

Tags: joomla-3.x, user

I have a request from a client that the joomla 3.2 is sending email to the admin to approve and to the user that they must wait to be approved, but they would like to have email also sent to the user on activation.
 "When the Activate button is pressed for a user please email them"

Is this possible or are there any plugins for this?

thanks

Comment: Your question appears abandoned. I see that you were online yesterday (it's good that you haven't drifted from the community). Please move this page toward a system recognized resolution by either 1. Accepting an answer , 2. Updating the question, 3. Posting your own answer then accepting it.  Awarding the green tick on resolved pages is important because: 1. It rewards the volunteer that provides the best support, 2. Informs researchers that there is a working solution on the page, and 3. Prevents the page from being bumped to the top of the questions list by a script.

Comment: Ok, little while since I asked it, to remember the exact details, but was happy with getting closer answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a plugin is available for the same purpose. It is called [**admin-approval**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/email-authentication/26059).

> This extension enables Email Verification of newly registered users. To further enhance the site security - after the email verification from the user, administrator approval will be required to activate the user account. It integrates with Joomla, Joomla + JomSocial

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this plugin.

Comment: Hello @shyam, I had found your plugin and enabled it, but could not see a change or where it was possible to edit or see these emails? Should it work, if you approve a user from the User Manager screen?

Comment: No, this will only email user if admin approves via approval link in email.

Comment: Ok, closer to what I need at least, thank you

Answer (score 1):

A notification email when the account is activated should be default behavior for Joomla.

[Enabling user's registration approval by admins](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_user%27s_registration_approval_by_admins)

> A new feature added to the user registration process in Joomla 2.5 and newer is the New User's Approval by Administrators, where a user will only be able to login after an administrator approves and activates the account.

Comment: Thats what I read but no email goes out after they are approved. They get an email to click a link to verify the account but not when the admin activates.

Comment: There is a slight problem with the link ;) I can't seem to edit it as the edit button seems to be disabled for this answer

Comment: The link seems fine now, so seems to be fixed.