# After admin approval, user does not receive acceptance email

Tags: user, registration

Hi I have two step registration setup in Joomla 3.3

The user receive an email with a verification link. It does not seem to matter much as they have to be activated by the admin.

However, how to automate an email to go to the user once the admin has activated their account?

Any advice or plugin experience would be great.

Comment: This isn't possible with Joomla. Clicking an activation link or an admin verifying an account with both activate it. Both do the same thing. There are no plugins that I personally know of, therefore you might need to write your own. Is it really needed to have an admin to verify an account and then have them also activate it via email? Surely 1 of the 2 would suffice

Comment: This is a feature I have requested too, as there is a human action so it would seem easy to have core updated to send an email action at this point. It is confusing to users if they get an email but then have to wait without confirmation for this to be done by an admin, and just keep trying.  http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/629/can-joomla-send-the-user-an-email-when-admin-approves-them?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_user's_registration_approval_by_admins) page, what you describe is the default behavior when you set user registration to "Admin":

> **Admin**
>
> It is necessary that an administrator approves the account. Here is
>   how the process goes:
>
> - After registering the new user receives an e-mail message containing a link with a token to verify their e-mail address;
> - After the user's e-mail address has been verified, all users with the Receive System Messages option enabled will receive an e-mail
>     message notifying them that a user has verified their e-mail address
>     and requests that their account be activated. That email message will
>     contain a link with a token to activate the account;
> - Once an administrator has activated the account, the user will receive an e-mail message notifying them that they may now login.

As an alternative, you might try a plugin called [Admin Approval](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/email-authentication/26059), it looks like it does the same thing.