# Can Joomla send the user an email after admin approves them?

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, user, emails

I refer to this ticket:

[Can Joomla send the user an email when admin approves them?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/629/can-joomla-send-the-user-an-email-when-admin-approves-them?newreg=bd222e22f6094cfbbe7d43c4495d1299)

hence I can not reply or comment as a new user does anyone know a solution to this issue of mine?

Problem is:

1. user registers at the side and gets registration email with a confirmation link
2. admin gets an email with notification
3. admin activates & enables the user
4. **no notification email to the user was send about his accounts activation**

thanks in advance for your time

Comment: The first question is "no email sent" or "no email received?" Working backwards from there, the thing to test is if the system can send *any* email to that user.  You might be able to walk the system logs (including the PHP log file) and check to see what is happening at that point.

Comment: Your requirements are relatively clear, how far did you get regarding solving each item? Do you only need help with 4 (since it is bold)? Did you write some scripts yourself or are you using an extension? @Carl

Comment: @Arlen Sry for not mentioning the registration mail to the user which goes through just fine.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, i need help with 4. I have no scripts involved or external plugins for administration. Just vanila Joomla 3.9.X

Comment: even adding true to the 'Admin activation is on and admin is activating the account' in the registration.php does not help. No log entries either so I assume that there is no attempt to send the mail after activation in the first place.

Comment: "so I assume that there is no attempt...": do not assume but test. Create (or use) an email address for the test-user, use the mail address when you creat a test account from the frontend of the site, test that a mail is sent after registering, click the confirmation link, check that you as an admin receive a notification mail, activate the user, check if you receive mail at your test email address. (Which describes a standard flow for Joomla registration.)

Comment: Are you activating the user through the link in the email or through backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla distinguishes between user activation by link through email or via administration backend. 
In order to send an email to the user after the activation of the user account one needs to use the link from the email. Activation from the administration backend will not send an email to the user who's account was activated.

Comment: Just a suggestion: You might want to accept your answer for this. Aside from benefitting your own reputation numbers here, it'll help guide future questioners with this issue to a working solution.

Comment: @Arlen Thank you.